# How do I select from a linked temp table, into a local temp table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently calling a stored procedure on a linked server. This stored procedure selects data into a temporary table on this linked server. I'm then attempting to select this data into a temporary table on the local server, so that I can manipulate the data and pull it into various tables.

If I manually run the stored procedure on the server, I'm able to run the second part of the query (--SELECT DATA FROM TEMP TABLE). However, although I'm able to successfully call the stored procedure via the first part of my query, when it gets to the second part, I get the below errors:

> ```
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 66
> Statement(s) could not be prepared.
> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 66
> Invalid object name '##Sales'.
> ```

Is there another method I could use here? SSIS isn't an option right now, the requirement is to code this via T-SQL.

```
--CALL STORED PROC FOR SALES DATA
DECLARE @RunSalesStoredProcSQL VARCHAR(1000);
SET @RunSalesStoredProcSQL = 'EXEC [SERVER\INSTANCE].[DATABASE].[dbo].[Extract_Sales_Data]';
        EXEC (RunSalesStoredProcSQL) AT [SERVER\INSTANCE];
        Print ‘Sales Procedure Executed';


--SELECT DATA FROM TEMP TABLE
SELECT * 
    INTO ##TempTable
        FROM OPENQUERY([SERVER\INSTANCE], 'SELECT * FROM dbo.##Sales');
        Print 'Data Selected';
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to have a meeting with all the responsible parties, especially the ones that control this procedure. It would be best for a stored procedure to produce the output directly so that it can be consumed without the use of this global temp table. Why? When does that table get dropped? Can you control that in this situation? You might be able to do this within a single batch executed at the linked server - but the better approach is to abandon this temp table design.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the data from linked server procedure as a simple select, not selecting it in a temp table, and then you can do the following on the local server:

```
INSERT INTO ##TempTable(ColNames)
EXECUTE [SERVER\INSTANCE].[DATABASE].[dbo].[Extract_Sales_Data]

--select data
SELECT * FROM ##TempTable
```